Is it possible to derive Rindler coordinates using inverse Lorentz transforms?
In page 8 of this notes, the author shows that accelerated observer's spacetime coordinates $(ct', x', y', z')$ is related to inertial observer's spacetime coordinates $(ct, x, y, z)$ by
$$
\begin{align*}
ct&=x'\sinh(g\tau/c) \\
x&=x'\cosh(g\tau/c) \\
y&=y' \\
z&=z'
\end{align*} \tag{1}\label{eq:1}
$$
where $\tau=t’$ is accelerating observer's wristwatch time.
It somehow reminds me of inverse Lorentz transforms:
$$
\begin{align*}
ct&=ct'\cosh\phi+x'\sinh\phi \\
x&=ct'\sinh\phi+x'\cosh\phi \\
y&=y' \\
z&=z'
\end{align*}.
$$
So if I put $\phi=g\tau/c$, I get
$$
\begin{align*}
ct&=ct'\cosh(g\tau/c)+x'\sinh(g\tau/c) \\
x&=ct'\sinh(g\tau/c)+x'\cosh(g\tau/c) \\
y&=y' \\
z&=z'
\end{align*}. \tag{2}
$$
It seems like in \eqref{eq:1}, $ct$ and $x$ do not include contributions from $ct'$. Why are $ct'\cosh(g\tau/c)$ and $ct'\sinh(g\tau/c)$ terms not necessary?

There is a treatment similar to what you may be looking for, in this Wikipedia article on proper reference frames. However, it requires familiarity with the tetrad formalism to really grasp. A similar treatment can be also found in MTW, chapter 6 - "Accelerated Observers".

Note, that the set of all Lorentz transformations forms a group called $\operatorname{SO}(1,3)$. Therefore, the inverse of a Lorentz transformation $\Lambda^{-1}$ is also a Lorentz transformation.

Your equations in $(2)$ don't make a lot of sense as a coordinate transformation. You have 3 time variables: $t, t' , \tau$, what does it mean?

@Amit I already defined that $\tau=t'$ earlier. $t$ is time as seen by inertial observer and $t'$ is time as seen by accelerating observer.

@user366875 Oh I see, sorry. One thing I can see then is that it creates a weird situation that these transformations won't be one to one. For example take $x'=0$ and $x=k$ for some constant $k$. These two spatial locations are related by time coordinates that obey an equation of the form: $$ k=t'\sinh(t')  $$ where I'm intentionally throwing away all constants. This will have two solutions for $k>0$ for example. It's far from a full answer, but maybe it's a bit helpful

Look here https://www.physik.uni-leipzig.de/~schiller/ed10/Uniform%20relativistic%20acceleration.pdf

No need for 1+3D, just focus on 1+1D. The whole point is that Rindler coordinates are not obtained by a Lorentz transformation (or their inverse, which is also a Lorentz transformation since it is group). Physically, this is because Rindler observers are accelerating so are not inertial. You therefore cannot reduce Rindler coordinates to Lorentz transformations.
Mathematically, Lorentz transformations are linear in $x,t$, with $\phi$ the rapidity is constant (usually denoted $w$). You will not gain much insight by varying rapidity. You should rather view Rindler coordinates as the hyperbolic analogue of polar coordinates with $x$ the radial coordinate and $t$ the angular coordinate, replacing trigonometric functions by hyperbolic ones.
What would make sense is to look asymptotically around each event in space time where at linear order, Rindler coordinates do become Lorentz transformations up to a scaling. You get (setting $c=1$, highly recommended when doing relativity):
$$
\begin{align}
dx &= \cosh(gt')dx'+gx'\sinh(gt')dt' \\
dt &= \sinh(gt')dx'+gx'\cosh(gt')dt'
\end{align}
$$
so up to the time scaling $gx'$, you do have have a Lorentz transformation of rapidity $w=gt'$
The Euclidean analogue is that in polar coordinates:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= r\cos\phi & dx &= \cos\phi dr-r\sin\phi d\phi \\
y &= r\sin\phi & d\phi &= \sin\phi dr+r\cos\phi d\phi
\end{align}
$$
up to a rescaling $r$ of the angle $\phi$, you have a local rotation of angle $\phi$.

Thanks for the answer. Why Lorentz transforms won't work with varying rapidity.
